# os.system on Windows 8

Tags: python, windows, os.system

I bought a computer and I have a problem with... Python os.system command. 
I've been using Windows 8 for almost a year and I didn't have this problem and now, after installing python and libs I cannot use os.system. Even when I just type `os.system("dir")` I get -1 as the output.

That is very strange and google says nothing.
I have Python 2.7.9.
Maybe I missed some dependencies? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: have you tried turning off your computer and turning it back on? you might needto reinstall python ...

Comment: yes, I did it even several times ;-) I will try with reinstalling, but I also tried to do this before

Comment: That most likely is an environment issue. What is PATH set to?

Comment: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;  in PATH and C:\Python27 in PYTHONPATH

Comment: EDIT: I had a mess in my PATH after reinstalling. Cleaned and solved!

Comment: I think @Jan-PhilipGehrcke has it figured out - your `PATH` doesn't have a path to `cmd.exe`. But how could that be?

Comment: Your `PATH` is definitely messed up, but I'll bet so is your `COMSPEC` (which is what `os.system` uses to locate cmd.exe).  try this `python -c "import os; print os.environ['COMSPEC']"`